# How to take chages from my IDE Eclipse to the run time execution for my plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime

Please I am using plug-in development tool in Eclipse. I run my plug-in like that: Run=> Run as=> Eclipse application another ide for execution opend and I see result, but when i change the code in my IDE of plug-in development I need to close the execution application and run again to see the new result. 
I want to modify in the IDE and keep see the new changes in the runtime-EclipseApplication there is way please to that ? thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Debug**=> **Debug as**=> **Eclipse application** will cause code changes to be swapped into the runtime VM as you make them, assuming Automatic building is enabled, just as it does for any other Java application. However, it will not make changes in your plug-in MANIFEST.MF or plugin.xml take effect--that still requires restarting and clearing the Configuration space.